# Having arrow keys send clicks when using QListWidget

Tags: pyqt

I've worked through the excellent Matplotlib GUI tutorial found at: http://blog.rcnelson.com/building-a-matplotlib-gui-with-qt-designer-part-1/. This program uses a QListWidget to select plots to show. Everything works correctly but I have one additional need. Once a item in the list is selected you can select the next or previous item with the arrow keys. The next or previous item is highlighted. What I want is a means to trigger the same event that is triggered by clicking. The click event is handled by the following code:

```
self.mplfigs.itemClicked.connect(self.changefig)
```

I've tried the following and neither works:

```
self.mplfigs.itemEntered.connect(self.changefig)
self.mplfigs.currentRowChanged.connect(self.changefig)
```

Much Google searching hasn't helped so any hints are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use itemSelectionChanged signal, in your case `self.mplfigs.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.changefig)` should trigger the function, I don't have the full code but that should work and please take look [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#itemSelectionChanged)

Adding a minimal working example:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import sys

class myListWidget(QListWidget):

   def Clicked(self,item=None):
    if not item:
        item = self.currentItem()
    QMessageBox.information(self, "ListWidget", "You clicked: "+item.text())

def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   listWidget = myListWidget()

   #Resize width and height
   listWidget.resize(300,120)

   listWidget.addItem("Item 1"); 
   listWidget.addItem("Item 2");
   listWidget.addItem("Item 3");
   listWidget.addItem("Item 4");

   listWidget.setWindowTitle('PyQT QListwidget Demo')
   listWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(listWidget.Clicked)

   listWidget.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Original code is take from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qlistwidget.htm)

Comment: I think you mean [`itemSelectionChanged`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#itemSelectionChanged)

Comment: I tried self.mplfigs.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.changefig) but it doesn't display the next or previous plot. Working in PyCharm I get: TypeError: changefig() missing 1 required positional argument: 'item'. I also get this using a click, but that does change the plot where as the arrow keys don't. I also added the if statement to changefig but that had no effect.

Comment: Also, the "testCall" should be "listWidget.Clicked".

Comment: I think the issue is when itemClicked is used it emits a QListWidgetItem where as when the itemSelectionChanged is used it doesn't.

Comment: @Achayan, your suggestions got me very close. I posted the answer that works below, but if you could edit your answer, I'd rather accept it to give you credit.

Comment: I don't know what you talking about .. I already had that in my code  def Clicked(self,item=None):
    if not item:
        item = self.currentItem()
So what was I missed ?

Comment: @Achayanm, In your first paragraph you refer to "currentIndexChanged" but your code example uses "itemSelectionChanged". While this works, it requires changefig to be modified because "itemSelectionChanged" doesn't emit a QListWIdgetItem. Using "currentItemChanged" instead works and doesn't need changefig to be modified. Also you code example has "testCall" which is undefined. It should be replaced with "listWidget.Clicked". As I said, I'd prefer to accept your answer, but it should be corrected first.

Comment: Okay I accepted that in my comment to reply for  Brendan Abel, Anyways I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

@Achayan got me very close. Here is what solved the problem. Using the following line is as was suggested:

```
self.mplfigs.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.changefig)
```

I needed to change changefig from:

```
def changefig(self, item):
    text = item.text()
    self.rmmpl()
    self.addmpl(self.fig_dict[text])
```

To:

```
def changefig(self, item=None):
    if not item:
        item = self.mplfigs.currentItem()
    text = item.text()
    self.rmmpl()
    self.addmpl(self.fig_dict[text])
```

Unlike itemClicked, itemSelectionChanged doesn't emit the item so the extra if statement was needed to get the particular item necessary within changefig.

However, the following line of code seems to work without modifying changefig.

```
self.mplfigs.currentItemChanged.connect(self.changefig)
```

Evidently currentItemChanged emits the item like itemClicked does.